# Openshift SSL Certificate Chain is Invalid (Mono/Unity)

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, ssl-certificate, openshift

I recently create an Openshift account to host my php website on it, and I'm currently trying to connect to it, and to do so, I have to disable certificate verification, as it's returning me

```
TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code:    0xffffffff80092012
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates)
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 ()
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg)
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Rethrow as IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Rethrow as WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ()
System.Net.WebClient.UploadValuesCore (System.Uri uri, System.String method, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data, System.Object userToken)
System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data)
```

And with further looking around, I found out with certificate the error was the chain [mono tlstest result]

```
[Subject]
  CN=*.rhcloud.com, O=Red Hat Inc., L=Raleigh, S=North Carolina, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc
, C=US

[Not Before]
  04/06/2015 20:00:00

[Not After]
  04/11/2018 08:00:00

[Thumbprint]
  46DC884F27EB05BDE0A478AE2300775FEF6E0E08


        Valid From:  04/06/2015 20:00:00
        Valid Until: 04/11/2018 08:00:00

Error #-2146762486: CERT_E_CHAINING 0x800B010A
```

But the certificate is not returning any errors when checking out the website or using https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/10oyr.png

I am using Unity 5.0 with Mono and my website was created via PHP
I also use WebClient.UploadValues(); to send the message (Because Unity doesn't support HttpClient - Only .Net 3.5)

Is there anyways I can fix this?

Comment: `WebClient.UploadValues(); to send the message (Because Unity doesn't support HttpClient - Only .Net 3.5)`, all tough it is true that it only runs 3.5. There are plenty of open source http client librarys available [just one for example](https://github.com/andyburke/UnityHTTP)

Comment: @MXD I'm more accustomed to use WebClient either ways, that was more of a notice for those who might answer with a non-supported method, but I appreciate the link ...